# Dataframe sub in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to substract a column with another in the same dataframe but I got only `nan`

input dataframe `diff`:

```
     circulating_supply_2
currency                      
BCH               1.822555e+07
BTC               1.816325e+07
ETH               1.092969e+08
QASH              3.500000e+08
XRP               4.365378e+10      
 circulating_supply_1
currency                      
BCH               1.823258e+07
BTC               1.817038e+07
ETH               1.093499e+08
QASH              3.500000e+08
XRP               4.365378e+10
```

My code:

```
diff = diff.iloc[:,-1:].sub(diff.iloc[:,-2:-1])
```

output:

```
          circulating_supply_1  circulating_supply_2
currency                                            
BCH                        NaN                   NaN
BTC                        NaN                   NaN
ETH                        NaN                   NaN
QASH                       NaN                   NaN
XRP                        NaN                   NaN
```

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: Im not sure why your subtracting that way, cant you do `diff['circulating_supply_2'].sub(diff['circulating_supply_1'])`

Comment: What are you expecting from this code `diff.iloc[:,-1:]`? @delalma

Comment: Simply do `diff = diff.iloc[:,-1:].sub(diff.iloc[:,-2])`

Comment: @Kenan I was doing it the implicit way. But thank you it worked

Comment: @Vishnudev I was expecting to get the last column

Comment: Ok will post it

Comment: @delalma please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you are satisfied here so this problem can be closed

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`diff['circulating_supply_2'].sub(diff['circulating_supply_1'])`

OR

`diff['circulating_supply_2'] - diff['circulating_supply_1']`